# Gdal ReadAsArray() different values than gdal band statistics

Tags: python, gdal

I am confused about why if I open a band with GDAL I get, for example, `band.GetMaximun(): 1000`, but if I do `ReadAsArray` I get `myArray.max(): 1200` (the same if I do `np.max(myArray)`). Does someone knows why this difference?

Comment: Could you share more code that highlights how you are loading your data and accessing your functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is most likely due to outdated statistics in your GeoTiff. `band.GetMaximum()` will read the value from the precomputed statistics, which are included in the GeoTiff.

If you want to update the statistics you can either use `gdalinfo -stats` or do it with the Python bindings, provided you have write access to the file.

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("myGeo.tif", gdal.GA_Update)
ds.GetRasterBand(1).ComputeStatistics()
```